# Regular Expression to check for letter, number, and symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a password in Javascript and require that it has a letter (upper or lowercase), a number, and a symbol.
This is the Regex I have

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\W)/
```

This does not seem to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I answered this question at last twice. Please search before asking.

Comment: Your regex is right and should work...Can u show us how are you validating and what should be the correct-incorrect output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a couple of asterisks.

`/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\W)/`

edit: The question was edited. The code now works as is.

Comment: Looks like the biggest problem was where I was actually checking against the regex. I have it working now. Thanks.